# Flask + apache + mod_wsgi + scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, flask, scipy, mod-wsgi

I have two Flask webservices that make use of Scipy/Numpy libraries. Due to  C extensions in both libraries, I followed directions mentioned in a few posts and websites and had both under %{GLOBAL} application group.
The problem I'm having is that the first app that I send a http request to returns valid results, while the second app will always return a 404.
If I deploy only a single app then each work fine on their own, and hence I believe that the issue has to do with the numpy/scipy C modules.

Below is the virtual hosts file.

Anyone has any idea how to solve the issue?

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/myuser/miniconda3
WSGIChunkedRequest On
<VirtualHost *:80>
                WSGIDaemonProcess app1 user=myuser group=mygroup
                WSGIScriptAlias /app1  /var/www/app1/app1.wsgi
                <Location /var/www/app1/>
                        WSGIProcessGroup app1
                </Location>

                WSGIDaemonProcess app2 user=myuser group=mygroup
                WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/app2/app2.wsgi
                <Location /var/www/app2/>
                        WSGIProcessGroup app2
                </Location>

                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel debug
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The ``Location`` directives in this should have been ``Directory`` directives. Without that the WSGI applications weren't actually being run in the respective daemon process groups.